# Labeling Singe Variable Data Points in Excel With Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a chart in Excel with Python 2.7, matplotlib, and xlwings.
I have the following chart but I only want to label the **Age** instead of both the Age and the helper column.

How can I do that?

Data

```
Helper  Age
0   9
1   30
2   27
3   40
4   45
5   56
6   44
7   21
8   45
9   45
```

Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xlwings as xw

# Data table
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", "Sheet2")


# My workbook.
wb = xw.Book('test.xlsx')

# Instantiate the worksheet.
sht2 = wb.sheets["Sheet2"]

# Dump Age column into a dataframe.
ageList = df['Age'].values.tolist()
helper = df['Helper'].values.tolist()


fig = plt.figure()

# Line plot.
plt.plot(ageList, ls = '--', color = 'red')

# Label the data points here.
for xy in zip(helper, ageList):
    plt.annotate('(%s, %s)' % xy, xy=xy, textcoords='data')

sht2.pictures.add(fig, name = 'TestPlot', update = True)
```

Chart

[image]

Comment: You're already annotating. Do you understand what's going on in your `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only annotate the value you want to annotate. In your case the y values?

```
# Label the data points here.
for xy in zip(helper, ageList):
    plt.annotate('(%s)' % xy[1], xy=xy, textcoords='data'
```